# Should "Example" have a capital letter when pluralised?

Tags: capitalization, academic-writing

When referring to different examples in a research paper, the *e* should be capitalised:

> 1. In Example 3, we see how...

But does this hold for the plural as well? That is, which of the following is correct:

> 2a. In Examples 3 and 4, we see how...

> 2b. In examples 3 and 4, we see how...

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think it should or should not? What concerns do you have about doing it either way?

Comment: @randomhead Same concerns as with any rules – I want it to be correct! Then again, I realise from James's answer that there are no hard and fast rules here, so... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions of capitalization, apart from the most basic rules, are principally a matter of style.

In this case, I think consistency would suggest writing "Examples 3 and 4" with a capital. But you would probably write "In the third and fourth examples".

However, if you prefer not to capitalize, I don't think anybody would criticize or even notice!

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense :)